# Tomcat кэширование данных для сервлетов

Tags: java, tomcat

Есть несколько сервлетов, при обработке запроса каждый читает один и тот же файл с диска. Т.е. при каждом запросе файл читается заново.

Есть ли возможность закэшировать этот файл?

Так, чтобы он читался с диска только 1 раз(при обработке первого запроса или при старте сервера), а в последующем брался из оперативной памяти.

Comment: Попытка кешировать что-либо, не сделав замеры производительности - большая ошибка. Надеюсь, Вы их сделали и уверены на 100% в том, что файловая система - это однозначно узкое место вашего приложения. Технологии дисковых хранилищ и методов доступа к ним оттачивались не одно десятилетие, и для большинства задач скорость доступа к ним не являются критической в плане производительности.
Касательно кеширования - многое кешируется и без вашего прямого в том участия, контроллером диска и операционной системой. Не стоит создавать очередной велосипед...

Comment: @AlexeyKholodkov Сервлеты в одном war-файле или в разных? Что у Вас - Tomcat или TomEE?

Comment: @kff Tomcat 8.0.35. War-файлы не использую, сервлеты лежат в одном webapp

Comment: Не уверен, но, вероятно, ничего не получится. Я знаю способ сделать глобальный объект для сервера, который будет жить от старта до  перезапуска, но он требует поддержки EJB. А для этого нужен минимум TomEE, а лучше JBoss/WildFly (можно и GlassFish, но он тормозной).

Comment: Судя по вопросу, вы случайно не конфиг там какой-нибудь имеете в виду? Просто тогда это не кеширование называется, а совсем другой юзкейс.

Comment: @enzo по сути - конфиг. У меня есть отдельный json-файл, из которого в сервлетах мне нужно дергать значения полей.

Comment: В таких случаях удобно Dependency Injection использоваnь. Можете взять для этого [`Guice`](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Servlets) в качестве IOC контейнера. Вариант 2, самый простой, добавить `ServletContextListener`, который на старте приложения десериализует ваш конфиг в Java бин и сохранит в `ServletContext` из которого вы его потом будете дергать в сервлетах. Вариант 3, использовать JNDI, Tomcat в этом случае [умеет возвращать один и тот же объект](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/globalresources.html#Resource_Definitions), проще говоря синглтон.